# Update a QLabel (several times) inside long running on click button function (slot)

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a graphical interface to a console program.

The program executes orders and periodically updates a `QLabel`.
The problem is that I can't get it to update dynamically, the function executes correctly but the `QLabel` is not updated until the end of the execution.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_10_clicked()
{
    estado_busqueda(2); // call function to change label, GUI should be updated immidiately
    system("sleep 2"); // some long running system call
    estado_busqueda(1); // call function to change label again 

}

void *MainWindow::estado_busqueda(int salida){
    if(salida==1){
        ui->face->setStyleSheet("image: url(:/media/sad.png);");
        ui->song_info->setText("no puede encontrar datos de tu enlace");
        ui->estado->setStyleSheet("image: url(:/media/search.png);");
    }
    else if (salida==2){
        ui->informacion->setText("Obteniendo data del enlace");
        ui->estado->setStyleSheet("image: url(:/media/esperando.png);");
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

Comment: hi ! i test but , /home/static/c++/c-/youtube/mainwindow.cpp:25: error: no viable conversion from '(lambda at /home/static/c++/c-/youtube/mainwindow.cpp:25:34)' to 'const char *'        QTimer::singleShot(2000,this,[this](){estado_busqueda(1);});

Comment: Opps, change `system("sleep 2");  estado_busqueda(1)` to `QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, [this](){estado_busqueda(1); };`

Comment: the compiler say expected "  ;  " i add QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, [this](){estado_busqueda(1);}); but continue no viable conversion :( ... this complete errro msg /home/static/c++/c-/youtube/mainwindow.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘QTimer::singleShot(int, MainWindow*, MainWindow::on_pushButton_10_clicked()::<lambda()>)’
     QTimer::singleShot(2000,this,[this](){estado_busqueda(1);});
                                                               ^

Comment: why estado_busqueda return a pointer?, change `void *MainWindow::estado_busqueda(int salida){` to `void MainWindow::estado_busqueda(int salida){`

Comment: i change but it still show inviable conversion :/

Comment: try with `QTimer::singleShot(2000,[this](){estado_busqueda(1);});`

Comment: /home/static/c++/c-/youtube/mainwindow.cpp:40: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2

Comment: mmm, are you using qt4 or qt5? If the SW version is not indicated then it is assumed that the OP is using the latest version

Comment: Qt Creator 4.12.4
Based on Qt 5.14.2 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)

Built on Jul 7 2020 10:07:04

Comment: no, analyze well if you have correctly configured QtCreator since the error you indicate is from Qt4 that does not support the lambda methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that I can't get it to update dynamically, the function executes correctly but the QLabel is not updated until the end of the execution

Widgets execute in the same thread, something [Qt refers to as main thread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html). Which means when you call sleep, you freeze the graphic thread. This explain why nothing happens.

As said in the comments `estado_busqueda` need to be a slot, and you should start a timer which will execute the next update on the button press. Basically @ eyllanesc suggestion should work

```
QTimer::singleShot(2000, this, [this](){estado_busqueda(1); };
```